# controller not found in basecontroller

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, laravel

I am using elastic beanstalk with laravel 4 and my code seems to be failing when i aws.push even though it runs fine on my local machine without any errors. There has been a deploy made with the similar code- i don't think i changed any namespace'ed items- it was only a few view/template changes

Basecontroller.php file hasn't been changed so i assume there shouldnt be any namespace issue?

```
<?php

class BaseController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Setup the layout used by the controller.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupLayout()
    {
        if ( ! is_null($this->layout))
        {
            $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
        }
    }

}
```

Heres the log being tailed:

```
symfony/translation suggests installing symfony/config ()
symfony/translation suggests installing symfony/yaml ()
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/config ()
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/yaml ()
symfony/debug suggests installing symfony/class-loader ()
symfony/event-dispatcher suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection ()
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/class-loader ()
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/config ()
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection ()
predis/predis suggests installing ext-phpiredis (Allows faster serialization and deserialization of the Redis protocol)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-amqp (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server (1.0+ required))
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-mongo (Allow sending log messages to a MongoDB server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing doctrine/couchdb (Allow sending log messages to a CouchDB server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing raven/raven (Allow sending log messages to a Sentry server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ruflin/elastica (Allow sending log messages to an Elastic Search server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing graylog2/gelf-php (Allow sending log messages to a GrayLog2 server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing rollbar/rollbar (Allow sending log messages to Rollbar)
aws/aws-sdk-php suggests installing ext-apc (Allows service description opcode caching, request and response caching, and credentials caching)
aws/aws-sdk-php suggests installing symfony/yaml (Eases the ability to write manifests for creating jobs in AWS Import/Export)
intervention/image suggests installing intervention/imagecache (Caching extension for the Intervention Image library)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Controller' not found in /var/app/ondeck/app/controllers/BaseController.php on line 3
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'Controller' not found","file":"\/var\/app\/ondeck\/app\/controllers\/BaseController.php","line":3}}Script php artisan optimize handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error



  [RuntimeException]                                                                                                            
  Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Controller' not found in /var/app/ondeck/app/controllers/BaseController.php on line 3  




install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [packages1] ... [packagesN]



2014-06-30 14:45:01,285 [ERROR] (1168 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-33] [root directoryHooksExecutor error] Script /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_composer_install.sh failed with returncode 255
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with AWS / Elastic Beanstalk, but the `Controller` class should be aliased inside your `app/config/app.php` file to `Illuminate\Routing\Controller`. It's possible your deployed app just hasn't run through that properly yet? Try `php artisan optimize` or similar commands until you can get it up-to-date.

Comment: bang on, i accidentally deleted the c from the Controller Alias on my server config file which was why the deployment was failing.